# How to declare a boolean OR object type?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Trying to create a variable which can either be `true/false`, or an object of `booleans`. I'm not very experienced with TS, is something like this possible?

`variableA: { a: boolean, b: boolean } | boolean`

Decided to work around it for now but would love to know if my syntax or approach is wrong.

[Example here highlights the main issue](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA9mwEsYDsAq5oF4oG8BQUhs8SyAggFxQBGMMANhAIbIFFyIoBCVtDzrAL548oSFGAAnCBADy1AFYQAxsHTjs%20IhKbVKxTmgxQAPjTqMWbQsF08DpddDN9LQkXgD0nqADkZACYAzhIwNNAArkEQAVAIyFAAzFABCABmaRDSyMBQAO5MIEEUIt5QAIwAlCkq9EzSEgAW0DCKKsAANPkwkgDWIWnxEHjKKEG5UjLySqpUk3Jtqk5QmtY6enOSERAda7bU9lra7CQo%20lLbu8cnhvZpTPTRa8LCXj4ATNXKzcq9UGk9CRbYCNECwBL7MhdPI9fr-IYldJQAAUAEJUfNpu0AHSQ6pHQijZBBfjY%20gwADmyIA5AEwiSALYQEHxCnUyp4V5lRJfH5-AGSKBgSRwLKgKDICDjGJxYkIAItRadJoivIhLIiwW6GARXIcUiUN5QAAKIsgknF1P1Z2pKRgUolMFyEAAHghxuCJMZqa4BKYHCgnNTsSazWKwVbTuRbXSHcgnVBXe69RDvfdHhBg8Agsj3olEgBODnpZGYpW43RkAD82Ot5HxayJJMYZMpNLpUEZzMarJoTGisRQAejHOEQA)

Comment: you can try it here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play

Comment: Yes, that's how you do it, it's called a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types). Did you run into some problem?

Comment: Are `a` and `b` fixed or that can be dynamic? Something like: `Record<string,boolean> | boolean`

Comment: `a` and `b` would be fixed yes. With my approach I get errors such as "This condition will always return 'false' since the types '{ a: boolean; }' and 'boolean' have no overlap.(2367)" sorry can't be more specific due to char limit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible to have it like this.

You can have an interface as well like this:

```
interface Iobj {
    a: boolean;
    b: boolean;
}

let myVar: Iobj | boolean;
```

Update:

```
if((treeObject.tabA as optionType)?.optionA) {
    console.log('do something based on optionA')
}
```

Comment: Updated the question with an example of my problem if you are able to look. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Seems to work, feels like there could be a more elegant solution somewhere? I don't like having to cast the type halfway through an if statement, feels odd to me. But this solves it for now

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. you need to define your custom `type` like this:

```
type variableA = { a: boolean, b: boolean } | boolean

var f:variableA = false;

console.log(f);

f = {a:true, b:false};

console.log(f);
```

Note that `variableA` is type not variable.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=9&ssc=16&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAbghgJwJZwEYBsIEEoF4oDeUcAXFKgPYWZwB2ANOWZdRHVAL5QA%205VNtALAAoEfARQAZiXEoM2PFLjoAzhADcIkQGMKtFawB06CgHMAFJICUm0cMmKCpYAgCuERqhKTlajrZ09A0xjM0sbIA)

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I updated the question with an example of my usage please let me know if that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

You can also write something like this:

```
interface ObjectOfBooleans {
    [key: string]: boolean;
};

type YourType = ObjectOfBooleans | boolean;
```

Or shorter:

```
type YourType = Record<string, boolean> | boolean;
```

You can store a true/false value or an object with any number of pairs of `boolean` type values into a variable of type `YourType`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I updated the question with a more specific use case (apologies).